# Load specific js & css based on class or ID?

Tags: css, page-specific-settings

I noticed that there are many tutorials on how to load specific JS & CSS for a specific page.

The problem I have is that sometimes my plug-ins load on specific posts and specific pages. I cannot have rules to define these pages or posts. Is there a way to load specific JS & CSS based on class or ID?

For example, I am using Next-Gen Gallery plugin. I want to program such that my site only loads Next-Gen' JS and CSS only when it sees this ID in the page (ngg-album). If possible, can I use wildcard, like if the page see any ID or class starting with NGG*, load Next-Gen JS & CSS.

Thanks!
Cliff

Comment: Think of it: Next-Gen Gallery plugin is able to add `'ngg-album'` class in the HTML using conditions handled in PHP. You can use same conditions to enqueue your assets. I don't know the plugin, so I can't tell you which those conditions are, but I guess that a shortcode is used, or a custom field is present or something like that.

Comment: Thanks G.M. The problem is that i dont know where in the code where it Next-Gen plugin add the 'ngg-album' class.  Do you know the function or the section of code i need to look for in the plug in?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry but no. I don't know the plugin so can't tell you where it does that. Maybe search for 'ngg-album' string in the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress [enqueues](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) javascript before the HTML is rendered so WordPress doesn't know what the class or ID is on the page.

What you MIGHT be able to do is [deenqueue](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_script) the Next-Gen gallery Javascript so it isn't loaded at all and then create your own Javascript file which loads the required Next-Gen JS if a particular class or ID is found. have a look at the jQuery function `getScript()` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/